# jquery clone does not copy event handlers

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery

I've a form and a button on click of which I want to repeat certain form fields. I'm cloning those form fields a domready and trying to add more of these on button click.

But i can add only one element. Even event handler for button is not working.

Here's my code -

```
<div id="word_exp_area" <?php echo($wi['work_exp_label'] == 1 ? '' : 'style="display:none;"'); ?> >
    <div id="xxx">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for='emp_name'>Employer Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="work_emp_name" id="work_emp_name"
                       value="<?php echo (isset($wi['work_emp_name']) ? $wi['work_emp_name'] : ''); ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for='work_date_start'>Date Started</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append date" id="work_date_start_control" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                    <input name="work_date_start" id="work_date_start" class="span2" size="16" type="text" readonly=""
                           value="<?php echo(isset($wi['work_date_start']) ? $wi['work_date_start'] : ''); ?>"/>
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                    <span class="help-block">yyyy-mm-dd format only.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for='work_date_end'>Date Finished</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append date" id="work_date_end_control" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                    <input name="work_date_end" id="work_date_end" class="span2" size="16" type="text" readonly=""
                           value="<?php echo(isset($wi['work_date_end']) ? $wi['work_date_end'] : ''); ?>"/>
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                    <span class="help-block">yyyy-mm-dd format only.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for='word_designation'>Designation</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="work_designation" id="work_designation"
                       value="<?php echo (isset($wi['work_designation']) ? $wi['work_designation'] : ''); ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for='work_scope'>Scope of Work</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="work_scope" id="work_scope"
                       value="<?php echo (isset($wi['work_scope']) ? $wi['work_scope'] : ''); ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="">Appointment Letter from Employer</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="file" name="app_letter[]"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="">Recommendation Letter from Employer</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="file" name="recommend_letter[]"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn add_employer" href="#"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Employer</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS -

```
var $formClone = $("#xxx").clone(true);

$(".add_employer").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $formClone.appendTo($("#word_exp_area"));
});
```

Set up [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ht3E/).

`Add Employer` button works one time only.

Comment: try, `.clone(true, true)`

Comment: i tried. It's not working with that either.

Comment: The copied div will have same id as the old one. Ids should be unique,  you could use css-classes instead.

Comment: @Esa Yes. I'm calling `removeAttr` after clone as it's not needed anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that if the clone function is moved into the click handler, everything works fine. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ht3E/1/):

```
$(".add_employer").click(function (e) {
    var $formClone = $("#xxx").clone(true);
    $formClone.appendTo($("#word_exp_area"));
});
```

Comment: yes. I was using same object and appending it to same container. So handler function was getting called but i couldn't see any change.